# How do I use an :active pseudo-class in CSS properly?

Tags: html, css

I tried my method here,

```CSS
.Subscribe-button:hover {
  background-color : rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.917); 
  transition       : background-color 1s;
  }
.Subscribe-button:active {
  background-color : black;
  }
```

and it works but you have to hold your mouse click for the event to happen and I want to make the transition activate only for the hover.
P.S. I'm new to HTML and CSS and this is just a sample of the code I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's the same transition selector and same element it will animate. One way to do that is to add a pseudo-element to the button and change the color of that one for `:active` instead. Here is how:

```css
.Subscribe-button:hover {
  background-color : rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.917); 
  transition       : background-color 1s;
}

.Subscribe-button{
  position:relative
}

.Subscribe-button:before{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:0
}
.Subscribe-button:active:before {
  background-color : black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Subscribe-button">Press Me</div>
```

Comment: I believe what his question was like that `:active` CSS triggers when the button is pressed down but he want to do it whenever he hovers. 

But that will just be `hover` state.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra background layer:

```css
.Subscribe-button {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.Subscribe-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.917);
}

.Subscribe-button:active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 0 0);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="Subscribe-button">Press Me</button>
```